# How to run Junit runner class in multiple time with same data?

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber-jvm

I need to run a Junit runner class multiple time which has 2 to 3 feature file

Comment: The best Stackoverflow questions have a bit of code in them.  What solutions have you tried? What tutorials have you looked at? What searches have you made and why did they fall short?

Comment: Can you provide additional information on what you are trying to do, preferably with an example.

Comment: i got some idea and implemented thanks

Comment: can you share your answer?

Comment: I kept my setpdef in loop and running from feature file